# Cannot compare in linq

Tags: asp.net-mvc, linq, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4, linq-to-entities

I am trying to get the result of the user logged in but receiving this error :

> "Cannot compare elements of type 'System.Linq.IQueryable`1'. Only
>   primitive types, enumeration types and entity types are supported. "

Here is the query I'm applying in my index action:

```
var viewModel = new PointsViewModel();
            viewModel.Point = db.Point.ToList();
            viewModel.Redeem = db.Redeem.ToList();


            TempData["UserPoints"] = null;
            var usrname = (from a in db.Instructors
                           where a.Email == User.Identity.Name
                           select new { a.PersonID });

            if (usrname.Count().Equals(0))
            {
                TempData["UserPoints"] = "You have not earn any points yet.";
                return View();
            }

            viewModel.instructor = db.Instructors
                   .Where(i => i.PersonID.Equals(usrname))// if I directly insert id here then it works properly but I don't want direct inserts
                   .Single();
            PopulateAssignedPointData(viewModel.instructor);
            return View(viewModel);
```

Please help me with this please...I am unable to find any solution on google

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's because you're passing `usrname` as a parameter to another query. `usrname` is a *query*, not a *value*, so you need to retrieve a value from the query (in this case, by using `First()`, but you could just as easily use `Single()` if you like) before you can use it as a parameter in another query. I would recommend the following changes:

```
if (!usrname.Any())
{
    TempData["UserPoints"] = "You have not earn any points yet.";
    return View();
}

var personId = usrname.First();

viewModel.instructor = db.Instructors
    .Where(i => i.PersonID.Equals(personId))
    .Single();
```

I also changed `usrname.Count().Equals(0)` to `!usrname.Any()` as it is more idiomatic (it will use the `exists` keyword in SQL, rather than `count`)

Comment: I am got this error when applying your solution "Unable to create a constant value of type 'Anonymous type'. Only primitive types or enumeration types are supported in this context. "

Comment: @UsamaSheikh: This is a piece of code that goes inside your function. It sounds like you're trying to put it outside of your function.

Comment: @UsamaSheikh: If this is the answer that you used (or was most helpful), please don't forget to mark it as the accepted answer for the question.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use this:

```
viewModel.instructor = db.Instructors
               .Where(i => usrname.Any(u => u.PersonID == i.PersonID))
               .Single();
```

Comment: `i.PersonID.Equals()` will return a bool, which is (hopefully) a different type to `u.PersonID`.  Not exactly sure what you're getting at, but as it is, it won't work.

Comment: Thank you @RoadieRich, I didn't update the code after copy-paste action.